# How to decompile an exe or a dll to assembly

Tags: dll, assembly, exe, decompiling

I am really interested in assembly language and I want to learn about how exe files work how dlls run etc... and I have an idea of writing an application to decompile an exe to assembly code since i am not a very good assembly programmer and with the lack of knowledge of the inner working of exe I couldn't do it. Since I can read an exe in hex i think it is not impossible but I don't know how to write my own program. Any resources or any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you're looking for a disassembler not a decompiler. IDA pro seems to be popular and you can download an older version for free at http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm

Comment: any way to decompile 64bit applications?

Comment: Sure there are. The newest version of IDA can do that (as can many others) it just isn't free.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of dissemblers already written for you (see above), but I don't think reading disassembled code is going to help you become a better assembly writer.  The main reason for this is that compilers do A LOT of optimization before they generate assemblies.  Often this makes for very tricky code to read but highly efficient code to analyze.

Comment: +1 it helps you (beginner in assembly language) getting confused

Comment: I down-voted this response since this is not an answer but just trying to discourage OP from trying to disassemble. On a second thought, since this is somewhat a valid comment, I wanted to undo the down vote, but SO won't let me do that.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in what a compiled program looks like at the a assembler level a much more meaningful approach would be compile and look at the generated assembly. For example with gcc/g++ this just requires `gcc -c -S filename.c` and will leave a clear text assembly file to look at.

Comment: This assumes you have the source code of the program, and that the programming that was used can be compiled by GCC such as C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Fortran, Ada, D, Go, and BRIG.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: you can disassemble object files too, for linux for example you can use `objdump`. But compiling your own code and looking what it looks like is simpler and allows for experimenting. Today it's still quite hard especially if you're compiling with optimizations; I remember however code generated by Turbo Pascal for 8086 that was really easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [Decompilation Wiki](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/DeCompilation), I suspect it will answer most of your questions.

Comment: I'm assuming you're going for general education, btw.

Answer (score 0):

reverseengineering.stackexchange.com (hereafter: re.se) has many resources/links to questions of similar scope:

- SO: [q/273145/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273145/) decompile windows exe 
  <- [comment](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2603/#comment21456_2603) on re.se
  <- [duplicate label](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/8038/) on re.se
- re.se: [q/26956/a#26962](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26956/a#26962) extract machine code