# Open MFC application to get source-code

Tags: mfc, reverse-engineering, decompiling

Does someone know how to open an MFC application to get the source-code?

(I want to know how it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC is compiled from C++ source, so it can't be recovered. You can use a decompiler on it, but the source you get back won't be particularly instructive.

There's a good related question on [debugging, disassembling and decompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly) you can check for more links.