# How to protect C# application from Decompilation and disassembly

Tags: c#, windows, security

It is assumed that once the exe is build, nobody can dig out the oi-outs of the source code or the application but after looking
[Is it possible to "decompile" a Windows .exe? Or at least view the Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly)

my assumption goes wrong. Then whats the way to protect our VS project if every logic is burnt inside the exe only.

If we use DLL developed in C# then can it be also decompiled ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988451/net-obfuscation for suggestions

Comment: @dash, the link provided appears to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to stop anybody from decompilation

You can use [obfuscator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/02/24/79236.aspx) to change the names of variables, methods or classes to make your code less understandable.

As per msdn.

> As for protection, there are a number of different schemes that
>   customers have told me about.
>
> 1. No protection. Some companies sell products that either ship with source code or have source code that can be bought separately, or have
>      chosen not to protect certain parts of their application that have
>      little IP.
> 2. Some companies use the obfuscator that ships with VS 7.1 (a “Community Edition“ of PreEmptive Solution's [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/index.html))
> 3. Some companies use one of the commercial obfuscators out there. There's a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vcsharp/team/tools/default.aspx) on the C# Developer Center on MSDN.
> 4. Some companies write the sensitive parts of their code in C++, compile that to an unmanaged DLL, and then use interop to call into
>      the unmanaged DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an obfuscator to accomplish your task.
You can find someone for free (with limited capabilities) and many commercial.
Search Google with "c# obfuscator" and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) to make it hard to disassemble.

Answer (score 1):

There are software licensing tools that allow you to encapsulate and encrypt your code using their security api's and tools. Have a look at SafeNet Sentinel LDK. Problem is its not free. But does allow you to provide additional security to your software's ip in addition to the above.

Answer (score 0):

You to use code obfuscation, that tool will change your code to form in which human cannot understand your code.

It would change your valid/readable function names to unreadable form . For eg, `GetPersonData()` to `__A___ASAS_()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805549/free-obfuscation-tools-for-net