# Decompling .net assembly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, deobfuscation

Hey i have done a few of decompiling  in .net as i am learning c# so it helps me to see codes as it helps a lot. But lately i have come acrossed few program that i know are .net but in reflector show up as non .net assemblies. Here is the example of program named: Proxy Multiply.

I am not trying to do any illegal stuff or something. Just trying to learn. I have tried to google this but i was not able to achieve any good result. 
Thanks
here is the link to image.

[image: Picture]

[image: De4Dot Error]

[image: PEid Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many .Net code protection alternative, that `obfuscate` the IL codes so that they are not that much exposed to IL disassembler application.

- .Net Reactor
- Themida
- SmartAssembly
- the list is huge . . .

many of the protector modify the Exe (PE Header info), .Net exe contains some extra MetaData that helps disassembler to identify it.

Download this little application it may tell you a little more about the exe.

Download [PEiD 0.95](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Packers-Crypters-Protectors/PEiD-updated.shtml)

> PEiD is an intuitive application that relies on its user-friendly
>   interface to detect packers, cryptors and compilers found in PE
>   executable files – its detection rate is higher than that of other
>   similar tools since the app packs more than 600 different signatures
>   in PE files.
>
> PEiD comes with three different scanning methods, each suitable for a
>   distinct purpose. The Normal one scans the user-specified PE file at
>   its Entry Point for all its included signatures. The so-called Deep
>   Mode comes with increased detection ratio since it scans the file's
>   Entry Point containing section, whereas the Hardcore mode scans the
>   entire file for all the documented signatures.

#### My best guess the assembly you are looking for is Protected by `.Net Reactor` or `Themida`

Comment: I will try and comment in few minutes.

Comment: Hey here is the screenshot of the PEid, i cant make anything out of it. Have a look. http://i47.tinypic.com/dpzs4k.jpg

Comment: And they thing that i dont get it is how can soo many decompliers can say that its not a .net assemble...

Comment: what reason u have for that particular exe being coded on .net language?

Comment: Because its requirement is .net4 ...and i have seen its companion files.... all are coded in .net

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with dot net reflector before,
try [JetBrains dotPeek version 1.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) Decompling(this application will show code that obfuscated)

> 1. Decompiling .NET 1.0-4.5 assemblies to C#
> 2. Support for .dll, .exe, .zip, .vsix, .nupkg, and .winmd files
> 3. Quick jump to a type, assembly, symbol, or type member
> 4. Effortless navigation to symbol declarations,
> 5. implementations, derived and base symbols, and more
> 6. Accurate search for symbol usages
> 7. with advanced presentation of search results
> 8. Overview of inheritance chains
> 9. Support for downloading code from source servers
> 10. Syntax highlighting
> 11. Complete keyboard support
> 12. dotPeek is free!

Comment: @user2177631:so if this not show code finally you must read IL code:D

Answer (score 0):

Just because it is .NET doesn't mean that you can just decompile it like that. They probably used ILMerge. That's not to say it's impossible but it will require more work.

See [Is it possible to “decompile” a Windows .exe? Or at least view the Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly)