# Unpacking from PerlApp executable

Tags: perl, perlapp

I create exe with PerlApp 9.4 but unfortunately I lost .pl source file. How can I restore it from exe?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but probably not easy.
See:

[Active State "Will people be able to decompile the executables I've made with PerlApp?"](https://community.activestate.com/faq/code-obfuscation#comments)

You will need to get familiar with decompilers:

[Is it possible to "decompile" a Windows .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly)

Consider using version control from now on for all of your work.  I recommend Git.