# Is it possible to decompile a .dll/.pyd file to extract Python Source Code?

Tags: python, dll, decompiling, extract, pyd

Are there any ways to decompile a dll and/or a .pyd file in order to extract source code written in Python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is not same question(dll not a .pyc file ) ! My idea No can't ! Maybe convert to assembly code but how to follow data/function tree ?

Comment: @Torxed this is indeed not the same question, pyd files are produced by Cython. Unlike pyc/bytecode, the pyd files are binaries that do not contain the original python source. Although it does not protect from reverse-engineering, it does make it a lot harder, and prevents someone from obtaining the exact original sources of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287253/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-compiled-pyc-file-into-a-py-file/78139684#78139684

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume the .pyd/.dll files were created in Cython, not Python?

Anyway, generally it's not possible, unless there's a decompiler designed specifically for the language the file was originally compiled from. And while I know about C, C++, Delphi, .NET and some other decompilers, I've yet to hear about Cython decompiler.

Of course, what Cython does is convert your Python[esque] code into C code first, which means you might have more luck finding a C decompiler and then divining the original Python code based on the decompiled C code. At the very least, this way you'll be dealing with translation from one (relatively) high-level language to another.

Worst-case scenario, you'll have to use a disassembler. However, recreating Python code from disassembler's output isn't going to be easy (pretty similar to divining the biological functions of a brain from chemical formulas of proteins that make up it's cells).

You might look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly) on ideas and suggestions regarding various decompilers and disassemblers, and proceed your investigation from there.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, I'll make sure to do some extra research.

Comment: @YoussefImam I don't agree with this answer, see my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41075212/1422096

Comment: @Basj Reading your updated answer, it seems that `.pyd` files compiled by Cython do not have source code embedded into them after all. If you could show it to be otherwise, I would be really interested, but until then, I'll stand by my answer.

Comment: @Basj, is it possible to reverse engineer the C-code then, there is this software that I need to reverse engineer, it is written in Python and has .pyd files in it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the accepted answer, it seems that yes, the content of the source code is accessible even in a `.pyd`.

Let's see for example what happens if an error arrives:

1) Create this file:

#### whathappenswhenerror.pyx

```
A = 6 
print 'hello'
print A
print 1/0 # this will generate an error
```

2) Compile it with `python setup.py build`:

#### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize("whathappenswhenerror.pyx"), include_dirs=[])
```

3) Now import the .pyd file in a standard python file:

#### testwhathappenswhenerror.py

```
import whathappenswhenerror
```

4) Let's run it with `python testwhathappenswhenerror.py`. Here is the output:

```
hello 
6 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\testwhathappenswhenerror.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whathappenswhenerror
  File "whathappenswhenerror.pyx", line 4, in init whathappenswhenerror (whathappenswhenerror.c:824)
    print 1/0 # this will generate an error 
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

As you can see the line of code `print 1/0 # this will generate an error` that was in the `.pyx` source code is displayed! Even the comment is displayed!

4 bis) If I delete (or move somewhere else) the original .pyx file before step 3), then the original code `print 1/0 # this will generate an error` is no longer displayed:

```
hello
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\testwhathappenswhenerror.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whathappenswhenerror
  File "whathappenswhenerror.pyx", line 4, in init whathappenswhenerror (whathappenswhenerror.c:824)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

But does this mean it's not included in the .pyd? I'm not sure.

Comment: Moving the `pyx` shows that the Traceback uses some sort of link from the `pyd` (`so` in Linux) to lines in the `pyx`.  The code is not in the `pyd`.

Comment: @Basj, if the pyx file is in same location and when you do `import whathappenswhenerror`, how do you know it's importing `.pyd` and not `pyx`? Probably it's importing `pyx` and hence the code display on error.

Comment: You can tell that it is using the `pyx` file by looking at the traceback (`File "whathappenswhenerror.pyx", line 4`)

Comment: Precisely, this answer is not correct. It seems, it's importing from .pyx

Comment: [An answer to a different question that convincingly shows that this answer is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62389335/4657412)

Comment: @Basj: Your answer shows that you have never done reverse engineering.

Comment: @Elmue I wonder what is the purpose of your comment? Make me feel inferior? I doubt this comment about what I have done or not done in my life is really useful for our community...

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong. And your answer does show how to get Python code back. Just displaying the name of a *.py file is NOT code! A stacktrace is not code. It is not possible to decompile Python code to the original. If you would ever have done REAL reverse engineering you would have opened a PYD file in a disassembler like IDA pro and see that you get nothing of the original code back.

Comment: @Elmue Ok, fine, then just downvote my answer. No need to elaborate about "what I have done" or "never done". `It is not possible to decompile Python code to the original`: *this* sentence is wrong. You can, for example with a .pyc file (different context from OP's question). I have already done it.

Comment: Nobody who sells a Python application will be so stupid to provide the PYC files. They are not available. And if you read the question correctly it asks for DLL/PYD files. The question does not ask for PYC files. So your answer stays wrong. You can delete it.

Comment: @Elmue This is not true. For your information, many applications were distributed that included .pyc file (or in a derivative way). Please read posts about decompilation of early versions of the Dropbox Windows client (coded in Python, with modified interpreter ; but still some people achieved a decompilation). Anyway this is out of topic, so I stop the conversation here.