# Extract images from an exe file that runs a slideshow

Tags: extract, exe, slideshow, photo

I have an exe file that plays a photo slideshow when executed.  The photos in the slideshow are from a family photo shoot and some of the family have since passed away.  The studio that created the file have since closed and I have no way of contacting them.

Can anyone help extract the files from the exe so that I am able to save them to get them printed for members of our family.

They are the only ones we have and would really appreciate any help in getting the photos extracted.

Thanks

Comment: Use print screen? I'm sure you can find tools to make taking screenshots more convenient, but that's the basic idea. Can't really give more specific advice than that. Reverse engineering is not easy and also not on topic for this site (and even if it were, I doubt anyone would be able to help with only the details provided here, because, without knowing which application created it, there can be pretty much anything happening in that exe).

Comment: Share us the tool who is used to create the exe

Comment: @BernhardBarker The print screen doesn't work as the images are not full screen are not suitable for printing the way they're presented in the exe slideshow.

Comment: @JRichardsz I don't know what the tool was as I was the client and just received the exe.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a software reverse engineering (SRE) framework. These kind of tools are able to decompile, disassemble or decompress executables or binaries: dll, exe, so, etc

I recommended you: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra

Another option is to use some compress/decompress tool like [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). With some luck and depending on how the exe was created, the images could be inside like winrar portables.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go of this and report back

Comment: I got Ghidra installed and loaded the exe into a project.  Can't find any identifiable information in that to help me work out what program is was created in.  Any others tips to help me please @JRichardsz

Comment: check https://www.shogunlab.com/blog/2019/04/12/here-be-dragons-ghidra-0.html   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly  https://superuser.com/questions/1565350/how-can-i-extract-image-files-from-an-exe  If don't work could be because the image is created at runtime, I mean the image does not exist as an attached file like java, android or ios apps.