# how do I decompile a flash .exe file into a .swf one?

Tags: flash, exe, swf-decompiler

**Problem**:
I want to decompile the `.exe` file of a Flash game into a `.swf` file (Adobe Flash file) so I can modify it

Comment: You cant. A `.exe` is not a flash file and is not remotely compatible with `.swf`.

Comment: This: https://www.swf-decompiler.com/flash-exe-extract

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: This post most likely talks about extracting the original .swf file from a "projector executable" created with Adobe Flash.

This bundles both a Flash Player and an SWF file together and creates a standalone executable. There is a simple extractor for this over at GitHub: https://github.com/laenion/dump_projector

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to turn a `.exe` into a `.swf`.

An `.exe` file is not a flash file and is not remotely compatible with `.swf`. The extension `.exe` stands for executable, meaning that it consists of machine code which gets run directly on the processor. A `.swf` acts as a fancy `.zip` archive containing assets and a form of cross-platform bytecode that is much more debugger friendly and contains lots of information about the code it was compiled from. Since a `.swf` is not an executable, you have to install a flash executable first which then is able to open a `.swf`, convert or interpret that intermediate bytecode into machine code, and runs your program.

That being said it is still possible to decompile a `.exe` into languages like C or maybe C++, but it is much harder and prone to breaking. You can refer to this page if you want to learn more about how that works: [Is it possible to "decompile" a Windows .exe? Or at least view the Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273145/5987669)