# Recover of the last successful build of a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, project, recover

Is there any way to get last successful build of a project? I have wrongly removed one of my WinForms. When I press Start, Visual Studio asks me to run the last successful build of the project and I say yes. I can see my removed WinForm when it runs in the last successful build, but how can i reach it's codes again? Regards.

Comment: 'Running the last successful build` just means it offers to run the most recent .EXE which resides on disk.  It is not convertible le to source code

Comment: Read up on how to use Git with your day to day dev work. Have you checked to see that your undo buffer doesn't go back that far?

Comment: You might be able to recover some code by [decompiling](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @stuartd. dotPeek decompiler helped me very much. I have recovred all of my stuff. You are my hero.

Comment: And @Flydog57, your advices helps me for my future project. In my projects i will use your advices. Thanks both of you again

Comment: Due to this build error, VS did not generate a new exe, but accessed the previously successfully built exe. At this time, you can decompile the exe. For details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273145/is-it-possible-to-decompile-a-windows-exe-or-at-least-view-the-assembly